# Tensorflow equivalent of Numpy's array[indices] = scalar

Tags: indexing, tensorflow

I have a tensor and an index tensor of the same rank. I want to set the values of the tensor that correspond to the indices in the index tensor to a certain scalar. How do I do this?

In other words, I'm looking for the Tensorflow equivalent of the following Numpy operation:

```
array[indices] = scalar
```

In my concrete case we're talking about a 1D tensor:

```
mask = tf.zeros_like(some_1D_tensor)

(e.g. mask = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Let `indices` be a 1D tensor that contains the indices of `mask` that I'd like to set to the scalar value 1. So I want:

```
mask[indices] = 1

(e.g. for indices = [1, 3] the output should be mask == [0, 1, 0, 1, 0])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it wasn't there before or if I just haven't seen it, but the general case equivalent of

```
array[indices] = scalar
```

is

```
tensor = tf.scatter_nd_update(tensor, indices, updates)
```

using [tf.scatter_nd_update()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd_update)